# Seeking advise on how to divide storage between Volume Groups and Logical Volumes on SSD and HDD disks for home server

Tags: lvm, storage

I am building a home server to host a few self hosted apps in docker (Ubuntu LTS). I would like to put all the files for the apps in the user home folder to keep them in one place and easy back up. I am thinking about 2 x main folders: /home/user/docker – for docker compose and all docker volumes and /home/user/data – for all my files:

```
/home/user/
        docker/
            container1
            container2
            …
        data/
            entertainment/
                    movies
                    series
                    music
            downloads/
            documents/
                photos/
                personal files/
            backups/
                laptop_backups/
                phone_backups/
```

I will assign the data/ folder to Nextcloud for access from family laptops and phones.

I have a 500GB SSD, 1TB HDD + a few different smaller size HDD’s + probably will add more HDD’s in the future. Maybe also one more SSD.

I am planning to divide the storage as LVM:

SSD – 2 partitions: 100GB & 400GB
HDD – 1 partition: 1TB

I will create 3 x Volume Groups: 100GB – “system”, 400GB – “SSD”, 1TB – “HDD”.

I am thinking about a following set up:

1. VG 100GB “system” – LV “system” for /
2. VG “HDD” – LV “slow data” for:

   ```
    /home/user/data/entertainment
    /home/user/data/backups
    /home/user/data/downloads
   ```
3. VG “SSD” – LV “fast data” for:

   ```
    /home/user/data/documents
    /home/user/user/docker
   ```

My question is: how to best divide the storage between Volume Groups and Logical Volumes? I would like to have a flexible set up so that I could resize and change disk storage in the future and at the same time use the SSD space in the best way.

Comment: that sounds like a bunch of old, small HDDs. Considering the price of prosumer 1 TB (ca [55€](https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/?cat=hdssd&v=k&hloc=de&t=v&sort=p&bl1_id=100&xf=222_5500%7E252_750%7E4930_1000) for 1TB of *fast* SSD) SSDs, hm, maybe retire your hard drive sooner rather than latrer and *only* have fast, more reliable storage? I think you're overengineering herding a bunch of HDDs that are probably getting close to the end of their lives.

Comment: and having a separate System volumne group seems inadvisable, altogether. It looks like you're essentially trying to reconstruct what a 1990's admin would have done on the inflexible partitioning approach to hard drives.

Comment: Isn't that what Volume Groups are for? Later If I change the drives I will just change the PV's in the storage Volume Group. And all my LV's will stay the same.

Comment: Yes but you don't need the volume groups for that. One would suffice!

Comment: One VG will not let me allocate the system to SSD and later resize when I change the drive.

Comment: It definitely does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to do something like this, but in the end concluded that splitting storage up into volume groups according to some combination of speed and intended use is counter-productive. It introduces an artificial limitation in how storage can be used, and the taxonomy doesn’t last long given the evolution of storage — your “slow data” may well end up being fast if you add a large SSD to the VG...

I recommend using a single VG for all your system’s storage, and for LVs where it matters, controlling which PVs they end up being stored on (which is easy to do if a PV has enough spare capacity when you create the LV, or can be done in other cases using `pvmove`). This also means that if you realise your choices weren’t perfect, you can still easily fix them, again using `pvmove` (and resizing LVs if necessary).

Comment: also: if you really have *enough* storage in principle and don't mind using your SSDs primarily as fast cache for mass storage, `man lvmcache`; haven't tried that, but always wanted to.

Comment: If I add more SSD's in the future would I not just add them to SSD VG and remap and copy LV's to the fast storage until the HDD VG is empty? If I for instance assign the whole 500GB to / and all my HDD's to /data folder I will just waste the space, as it will never get used. I now have barely 50GB in use for /.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I looked into it and lvmcache actually sounds like the best option to use the free SSD space! I could allocate 100GB to the system. Assign /home LV to the HDD VG with cache using the rest of the SSD.

Comment: It would make little sense to share an SSD between regular and cache usage. You only get its bandwidth once.

Comment: So it should be all or nothing in regards to cache? Either one VG with HDDs and SSD as cache or my original set up. Unless I get one more SSD.

Comment: It's sensible to assume that you want an SSD either to be cache or be permanent storage. Nothing more, nothing less is what I said. I'd follow Stephen's advice, use fewer different volume groups anyway, your original setup seems to have no advantages in any way, but complicate things unnecessarily. As Stephen says, you can have a mixed-device volume group but create volumes on specific underlying physical volumes.

Comment: I did some more searching and now your recommendation makes so much sense, thank you! I didn't know that LV's could be assigned to certain PV's. I can achieve same set up that I wanted just by selecting which PV to assign during LV creation.